# Efficient Data transfer between objects - C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have an program that loads a DLL and instantiates a pre-defined object. This object has a number of properties whose names are defined in an XML file. My program need to get/set these properties within the instantiated object.

I am looking for patterns/methods to do the same.

I cannot use Reflection because this Get/Set methods are called continuously in a loop in my program. Using reflection is very costly.

Do any of you guys have any best practices that you use for such scenarios??

Note : If required, I can change the *structure* of the object that is dynamically loaded from the DLL (I am developing it) but my program doesn't know the names of the properties of the object (The DLL is also being generated dynamically, so essentially, the *user* specifies the members required in the object and another program generates the code files and compiles them into the above mentioned DLL. After this, my program loads this newly generated DLL and starts it's work. So, I can change the *structure* of the object in the DLL but I do not know before-hand the properties contained in the DLL object.)

Comment: Using Reflection is not necessarily costly - it's done in some of the fastest libraries about including the .NET Protobuffer implementation(s). There are a number of nifty tricks that can make it significantly faster than a basic implementation.

Comment: Try: http://automapper.org/

Comment: @pst I am looking for alternatives to reflection. My current solution is using reflection. I want a solution that can be implemented in any language. I feel using reflection ties my design to .NET.

Comment: Using .NET ties your solution to .NET. I'm not sure I follow that reason :) In any case, there are already numerous examples of such pre-generated "non reflection" mappings such as sqlmetal (LINQ2SQL), wsdl (XSD/SOAP), and protofiles (Protocol Buffers). Note that these are only particularly beneficial *if the resulting types (or interfaces) can be used in a statically-typed manner* (from source that is compiled).

Comment: Exactly. I'm looking for something that works with dynamic types. I am going ahead with delegates. Will update the question if i come up with anything.

Comment: @pst Yes. Using .NET ties my solution to .NET. But I want my design to be easily implementable in other languages too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late already, I will suggest the following approach.

Design your external program so that,

1. It structures the user input as an xml file.
2. Generates xsd files via Xsd.exe tool which is shipped with .Net Framework SDK
3. Generates classes from the xsd files again using xsd.exe

This way you can have your main application, deserializing pure xml to classes generated by your external program. In the end it should look like the following and have little code to mantain.

External Program: Xml Data -> Xsl Schema -> GeneratedClasses

Main Application: Xml Data -> Deserialize to Instance

Comment: I am doing something similar now. The problem is not with the instance generation. I have completed that part. Since I do not know before had what properties are present in the object, I have to rely on Reflection for accessing those properties of the object. I  want an alternative for that.

Comment: @RaghavendraKumar My suggestion has no reference to reflection at all.

Comment: Ohh ok. Sorry, My bad. But I want this to be done hundreds of times a second. Will the method you explained be fast enough?? Since it seems to use a lot of disk resources.

Comment: @RaghavendraKumar In your main application you don't have to write any data to disk. Your two applications should share type information via xsd files. And main application could generate data in memory with given xsd. Actually this needs a proof of concept. I don't know even if it will work to be honest. But your requeriment that two applications will share type metadata and will not use reflection, leads me to xsd and xml serialization.

Comment: Ohh ok. I'll look into it and get back. Thanks !